# When should I calculate the probability of an event as if it were independent and when should I not?

Tags: probability

There are 129 coins on a table, one of them is biased, Bob picks a coin from the table and flips it 8 times, it falls heads on all of them, what is the chance that on the ninth try it also falls heads?

If we let $H_n$ denote the event that the coin falls heads in the first $n$ throws. Let $T$ denote the event that the coin falls on heads on the 9th throw. We search for $\mathbb {P}(T|H_8)=\frac {\mathbb {P}(H_8 \cap T)}{\mathbb {P}(H_8)}=\frac {\mathbb {P}(H_9)}{\mathbb {P}(H_8)}$

We condition on $B$ (the event of picking an unbiased coin) to find $\mathbb {P}(H_n)=\mathbb {P}(H_n|B)\mathbb {P}(B)+\mathbb {P}(H_n|B^c)\mathbb {P}(B^c)=(\frac {1}{2^n})(\frac{128}{129})+(1)(\frac{1}{129})$

Substituting we get that the desired probability is $0.83.$

I think this makes intuitive sense since heads coming up 8 times in a row is more likely given that the biased coin was chosen. However, why should the ninth throw not be independent? Why should I not just calculate the probability of throwing heads the first time?

Maybe I should, how can I tell when to do one or when to do the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ninth throw is [conditionally independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence) of the first eight given the condition $B$ or $B^c$. This is because if we know the probability of a coin to land heads, tossing it doesn't give us any further information on whether it will land heads in the future. But in the present case we don't know that probability, so tossing the coin does give us new information. This may be clearer if you think of just two coins, one that always lands heads and one that always lands tails. Conditional on which one you pick, all throws are independent, but if you randomly pick one of them, all throws are maximally dependent, though considered individually they appear as throws of a fair coin.

Comment: So my above calculations were incorrect? I should just calculate the probability of the coin landing on heads?

Comment: @GuachoPerez: No, I'm sorry if what I wrote led to that misunderstanding. Your calculation is correct. You hadn't formulated a question about your calculation, and I agree that it makes intuitive sense, so I didn't address that and only wrote to answer the question you posed, why the ninth throw in the unconditioned scenario isn't independent of the other throws. I suspected that what led you to think that it might be independent was the fact that it's conditionally independent.